# EXCEL / POWERQUERY/ VBA - Merge Two tables with multiple entires

Tags: excel, vba, join, merge, powerquery

I have two files, which are generated by two sources. Lets call Source 1 and 2 with 9 and 16 columns respectively. Combine/Merge these two files to get a total of 23 columns.

[image]

Requestor Access ID and Admin Access ID are common columns from both source. A single Requestor can have multiple entries in both tables. For example., 1234500007 is present twice, the first request is only for VIEW (Column G in Source 1) and second request is for EDIT/UPDATE. How do I perform merging the tables, and get the desired FINAL table, which will merge the information from Source 2 into Source 1.

I have used PowerQuery, but I have inserted a RequestNumber column for each tables, and got the Final table.

Is it possible to join these two sources without an unique column, if so what methods/techniques should i follow to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the query editor, when you do a merge, you can hold down CTRL to select multiple columns to merge on.

Like this:
[image: Merge]

Image from this article: [Merge Data Based on Two Columns](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2015/10/28/merge-data-based-on-two-columns/)